# where is rabbitmq config file?

Tags: rabbitmq

Documentation says that rabbitmq has config: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf 
but I have nothing there, but rabbitmq-server is running and consuming messages.

Where is my config file?

Comment: Which operating system and package manager are you using?

Comment: It was my fault, cause "by default /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config" is not created and one should create it manualy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I find the 'rabbitmq.config' file while I have already installed RabbitMQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38988356/why-cant-i-find-the-rabbitmq-config-file-while-i-have-already-installed-rabbi)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends in which way you install RabbitMQ. The file usually is not present.
If you need it, you have to create it.

For example if you use the package:

```
rabbitmq-server-mac-standalone-3.4.2.tar.gz
```

You can find the example file:

```
etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config.example
```

and not the file.

Using `RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE` you can specify the rabbitmq.config file, to be sure you can check this variable.

Comment: Run this to see if you have the config file somewhere: `echo $RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE`

Answer (score 6):

**On Windows:**

## RabbitMQ 3.7.0+

#### `%APPDATA%\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq.conf`

In RabbitMQ 3.7.0+, the main configuration file is `rabbitmq.conf`. An additional config file named `advanced.config` is also used for some advanced configuration settings; it uses the classic format.

## Prior to 3.7.0:

#### `%APPDATA%\RabbitMQ\rabbitmq.config`

The configuration file is named `rabbitmq.config` and uses the [Erlang term format](http://erlang.org/doc/man/config.html) (aka the "classic format" for RabbitMQ config files).

## Example files:

- [rabbitmq.conf.example](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/master/deps/rabbit/docs/rabbitmq.conf.example)
- [advanced.config.example](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/master/deps/rabbit/docs/advanced.config.example)
- [rabbitmq.config.example](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/v3.7.x/deps/rabbit/docs/rabbitmq.config.example)

Answer (score 1):

the default location of the config file is :

```
/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf
```

but If you are running Rabbitmq in a  docker container and you want to inspect all the files like the config files and the log files you can run the command

```
docker exec -it container_name bash
```

then you run the following command :

```
rabbitmq-diagnostics status
```

you will find the real location of your config and log files and many more informations like the enabled plugins the memory and so on .
also you can run the following command to get more informations like the consumer_prefetch the vhost and more

```
rabbitmq-diagnostics environment
```

Answer (score 0):

The default location of RabbitMQ is

```
/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
```

The default installation of RabbitMQ doesn't create any configuration file, to override/set any specific configuration, we need to manually create the config file on the default configuration location. Please refer to the below rabbitMQ documentation related to the same.

[Rabbit MQ Configuration](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html)

[Rabbit MQ Configuration File Location and Environment Variables](https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html)