# Why can't I find the 'rabbitmq.config' file while I have already installed RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.2, I have installed RabbitMQ and `systemctl status rabbitmq-server` shows

> ● rabbitmq-server.service - LSB: Enable AMQP service provided by
>   RabbitMQ broker    Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/rabbitmq-server)
>   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-08-17 11:25:56 JST; 1h 14min
>   ago
>        Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

But when I want to configure it I cannot find the file: `find / -iname "rabbitmq.config"` shows nothing.

I have an application which connects to `127.0.0.1:3000`, but the default port listened by RabbitMQ is 5672, so I want to add the port 3000 (hope it will fix the problem)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

RabbitMQ by default does not create the config file.

you have to create it, usually the location is:

```
/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
```

See: https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html

and

https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html

in 2021, 2022 i had to get the rabbitmq config file from their github:

- https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/main/deps/rabbit/docs/rabbitmq.conf.example
- i recommend using github to switch to the tag of your rabbitmq installed binaries to ensure the config file is compatible
- i would prefer the installer came with the example file but it does not to my knowledge
- then once you have the example config file you have to rename it `rabbitmq.conf` and put it in the correct location (see rabbitmq configuration docs because the directory is different for each distro)